# Problem with parametric equation in Python

Tags: python, parametric-equations

I am trying to determine a point x,y on a circle with a radius r for which I want to apply a paramteric equation as described on:
https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html

```
import math

radius = 45
t = 10

x = radius*math.cos(t)
y = radius*math.sin(t)
```

For x and y I get the following output:

```
x
Out[217]: 5.253219888177298

y
Out[218]: 8.509035245341185
```

I don't understand why. As far as I understand, x and y should have the same value if r is 45. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that t is 10 here.

When the input for t  is 45 degrees then they should give you the same value. You have to convert them to radian though.

```
import math

radius = 10
t = 45

x = radius*math.cos(math.radians(t))
y = radius*math.sin(math.radians(t))
print(x,y)
```

gives us

```
7.07106781187 7.07106781187
```